# solve an integral with negative infinity and infinity as bounds

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\cdot e^x}{1+e^{2x}}\mathrm dx$$

I have tried the substitution $u = e^x$, but I got stuck.

Comment: I have edited your post to make it more clear, please check that I did not change the _meaning_ of your post.

Comment: A fundamental step when dealing with improper intervals in general is FIRST to study its existence. Further calculation has no sense if you don't establish first the existence of the integral. Answers below should contain this.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\cdot e^x}{1+e^{2x}} \  dx$ as

$$ \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{x\cdot e^x}{1+e^{2x}} \  dx + \int_0^\infty \frac{x\cdot e^x}{1+e^{2x}} \  dx$$

Now, what happens if you substitute $x \mapsto -x$ in the first integral? In other words, is the integrand an odd function?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer / hint:
Multiply numerator and denominator of integrand with $ e^{-x}$ to recognize if it is odd or even.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the problem wasn't
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{xe^x}{e^{2x}-1}dx
$$
That function is even rather than odd, so the integral is non-zero, and in fact, is something like $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$.